# How to set multiply rules with and without expression in ng-class directive?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to use directive called `ng-class` to set multiply rules from CSS file. 
Here is a part of code

```
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail" 
        ng-class="{ filterToggleBtnSide notificationColor:notificationState }">
</div>
```

Variables `filterToggleBtnSide` and `notificationColor` contains a string names of CSS rules.

Variable `notificationState` sets `true` or `false`.

The point of question is - How I can always use `filterToggleBtnSide` rule , and `notificationColor` only then `notificationState` is true.

I was trying to make like code below

```
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail" 
        ng-class="{ filterToggleBtnSide && notificationColor:notificationState }">
</div>

<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail" 
        ng-class="{ filterToggleBtnSide, notificationColor:notificationState }">
</div>

<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail" 
        ng-class="{ filterToggleBtnSide:true, notificationColor:notificationState }">
</div>
```

In last sample only second expression is working.
I will be very appreciated if somebody help ;D Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
$scope.filterToggleBtnSide = "class1";
$scope.notificationColor = "class2";
```

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail class1" 
ng-class="{class2:notificationState }"></div>
<!-- or this -->
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail" 
ng-class="{class1: true, class2: notificationState}"></div>
<!-- or this -->
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail class1
{{notificationstate && notificationColor}}"></div>
<!-- or this -->
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail class1
{{notificationstate && 'class2'}}"></div>
<!-- or this -->
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail 
{{filterToggleBtnSide}} {{notificationstate && notificationColor}}"></div>
<!-- or this -->
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail 
{{filterToggleBtnSide}} {{notificationstate && 'class2'}}"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, I forget to say that '$scope.filterToggleBtnSide' can sets a different value. In my way, it can be like 'class1-left' and 'class1-right'. Any way, Thank you! Your answer help me to do 
<div class="filterToggleBtn thumbnail {{filterToggleBtnSide}}" 
ng-class="{notificationColor: notificationState}"></div>

But it's looks not so cool, cause I want to separate AngularJS things from standard HTML things.